# how to check and confirm a right opengl version with vcxsrv (for using ros2 rviz2)

Tags: xorg, opengl, ros

i have a remote-host (ubuntu 20.04),

and a local-host (win10 pc, with nv rtx3050ti gpu, updated driver), i started `vcxsrv` on local-host by(`win\cmd`):
`vcxsrv.exe  -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -ac`

then with `win\cmd` on local-host, i ssh to remote by:

```
set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
ssh -Y username@remote-ip
```

i don't know why it first need `set DISPLAY...` in `cmd` then `ssh -Y`, but it works for the started `vcxsrv` to display something, e.g., `xclock` or `rqt` (one of ros2's gui tools) will display as expected on local-host.

but when i try to start `rviz2` (another ros2's gui tool), on `ssh\bash` i got error like:

```
...
[ERROR] [1665571456.729849309] [rviz2]: RenderingAPIException: OpenGL 1.5 is not supported in GLRenderSystem::initialiseContext at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rviz-ogre-vendor-8.5.1/.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1201)
...
...
...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unable to c
```

among which, the key-error should be:

```
RenderingAPIException: OpenGL 1.5 is not supported in GLRenderSystem
```

i understand it's something with the opengl version, so i checked the followings, but still found nothing can further do, any help would be appreciate, thx:

`glxinfo -B` in the ssh prompt(`ssh\bash`) on local-host(with `set DISPLAY...` and `ssh -Y`):

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
name of display: localhost:10.0
display: localhost:10  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.6.0 NVIDIA 512.96)
```

then as some suggested, i tried (on `ssh\bash`)

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3
```

then got (`libGL error` disappeared)

```
name of display: localhost:10.0
display: localhost:10  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.6.0 NVIDIA 512.96)
```

`glxinfo -B` in the `ssh\bash` (without `set DISPLAY...` and `ssh -Y`, just `ssh`):

```
Error: unable to open display
```

directly `glxinfo -B` in the terminal in remote-host(`ubuntu20.04\bash`):

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 21.0.3
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 31893MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

i know nothing much about how x11/vcxsrv/opengl works, but don't understand why the opengl version is different when i check `directly` in remote-host or with `ssh` in local-host.

since other graphic-ui could displayed as expect(`xclock`, `rqt` of `ros2`), but `rviz2` of `ros2` could not, i think it's the dependency of `rviz2` with `opengl`, but why and how to ensure the right opengl version for my case/env?

thx

Comment: To be clear all these commands and errors are being run on a Windows machine?

Comment: hi, these cmds and errors are from `win\cmd`(direct at local win-host), `ssh\bash` (sshed to the remote linux-host), and `remote ubuntu\bash`(direct on the remote-linux-host), to make them more clear, i already edited the question

Answer (score 0):

glad to figure it out, not theoretically clear but quite practical, should start the `vcxsrv` on `local-host` (win10) side (`win/cmd`) with:

```
vcxsrv.exe  -multiwindow -clipboard -nowgl -ac
```

where, should use `-nowgl` other than `-wgl` at the beginning

Comment: update for remote server use-case(ssh with mobaxterm), maybe `sudo apt-get install libosmesa6-dev` should need, as `https://answers.ros.org/question/210688/rviz-and-opengl/`